# Can Islam be proven to any human being using logic only?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, shirk, imaan, doubts, other-religions

I hope if someone can prove Islam to me (and to anyone who reads this) in a way that is based on facts, way that applies to human logic and can't be denied.

It is well-known that most religious people are having a happy life, and I wish to have one too, but which religion is the most logical? or is Islam the absolute truth?

Comment: You ask whether Islam can be proven to someone who uses logic then go on to mention that you don't want to use logic because you think there could be a "higher level of logic." The latter is not something logical. It is basically denying that logic is a way of knowing anything.

Comment: I said that, logically, it is possible that there is a higher level of logic; because there are questions about existance which logic can't answer or even recognize.

Comment: No, it is not logically possible for there to be a "higher level of logic" and if you think it is, it really seems like you do not understand logic in the first place.

Comment: @TheZ, I think you mean that logic has nothing calculatable or can be compared, right?

Comment: No, I mean logic in its purpose is meant to lead to conclusions that do not depend on your level of mind. If you think there are things outside logic or that logic could be wrong because there could be higher levels, that defeats the purpose of logic.

Comment: @TheZ, these conclusions could be wrong; because they are limited to our consciousness. Logic is just linking objects and actions together, but it isn't always correct.

Comment: @AZeed, do not add comments into your post to respond the answerers. There is comments section under each answer post. Leave your comments there. Be reminded that comments are to improve the post.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

### Can Islam be proven to any human being using logic only?

This question consists of two parts.

1. Can Islam be proven (at all whether using logic only or otherwise)?
2. To any human being?

**1. Can Islam be proven?**

Yes. Islam can be proven. Infallible Prophets, Messengers and Imams are Hujjah (proof) of Allah upon creation, along with Ayat (signs). Anything related to Islam can be proven with them.

**2. To any human being?**

This is where problem lies. It depends on one's intellect. The answer is Islam can be proven only to those who use best of his A’ql (intellect) and purify himself from Jahiliyya (Ignorance). A’ql and Jahiliyya are opposite concepts. They are antipodes of each other. A’ql is assistant in recognizing truth (proof) where as Jahiliyya is obstacle. So Islam can be proven to those who use A'ql (intellect) and cannot be proven to those who are Jahil (ignorant).

Imam Abu Al-Hassan Musa Bin Ja’far (as) said following (in a long Hadith)

> ...Allah (azwj) did not Send His (azwj) Prophets (as) and His (azwj)
> Rasools (as) to His (azwj) servant except that they (as) would be
> using their (as) intellects about Allah (azw)...
>
> [Al Kafi V 1 - Part1 (Page 13)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol1/AlKafiV1-TheBookOfIntellectAndIgnorance.pdf)

In fact, so called test of human life in this Dunya is actually test of his A’ql (intellect).

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Ja’far (Imam Al-Baqir) (asws) having
> said: ‘When Allah (azwj) Created the ‘Aql – intellect, He (azwj)
> Interrogated it, then Said to it: “Come!” So it came. Then Said to it:
> “Turn back!” So it turned back. Then He (azwj) Said: “By My (azwj)
> Might and My (azwj) Majesy! I (azwj) did not Create any creature which
> is more Beloved to Me (azwj) than you, nor will I (azwj) Perfect you
> except among the ones whom I (azwj) Love. But, it is (based on) you
> that I (azwj) shall Command, and for you I (azwj) shall Forbid, and
> for you I (azwj) shall Punish, and for you I (azwj) shall Reward”’.
>
> [Al Kafi V 1 - Part1 (Page 3)](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol1/AlKafiV1-TheBookOfIntellectAndIgnorance.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. Please include [this link](https://keystotheunseen.com/islam/) I recently found, which proves Islam in an undoubtable way

Comment: Sorry. I cannot include it. It is Najas (Impurity). My answer comes from teachings of Ahlul-Bayt. Have you read verse [33:33](https://quran.com/33/33)? It says that Ahlul-Bayt is Tahir (purified). So the knowledge they teach is also Tahir (purified). I cannot defile pure knowledge by mixing impure knowledge into it.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to prove Islam (or any other religion) based on reason and observation, nor is it possible to refuse it on the base of reason and observation; because Islam is based on revelation, and revelation is not subject to observation (I use the word observation here in the sense "be watched at", not in the sense "to be obeyed"). We follow the revelation out of faith and trust.

It is possible to think of a senseful reason for all commands, images, warnings and encouragements we received; but again, it cannot be *proven* that the assumed reason is the true reason of God.

It is possible for a believer to pray to God and receive answers from Him. However, these answers are in the scope of what a human is able to think, so that there is no evidence, let alone an externally visible evidence that this answer is divine inspiration.

Through Islam, we received a guidance that cannot be obtained through logic because logic can only observe the relation between given facts (if..then), but it does not set a final goal of itself. And we can't live in faith alone without logic and reason because many things on the way to the given goal need to be decided through reason.

Off cause, almost everything *can* be doubted. But does doubt provide guidance as His word does?

Comment: Which religion should one follow then? follow his father's religion? or the most followed religion? or the one that satisfies him the most?

Comment: Islam is the most comprising religion - at least theoretically as it comprises Jewish and Christian relevation, too. You would of cause get a different answer on Buddhism se ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think Islam can be proven in a logic way.
First science says there was a Big Bang, some researchers have found that the probability of life appearing from this chaos is nearly equal to zero, even billions of years after the Big Bang.
So we only have 2 choices here :

- Believe that was by chance
- Believe there has to be an almighty God who is supervising all that.

In our everyday life, we forget that life itself is a miracle.
Life is not made by science, science is trying to understand life, and the billions of elements that allow me to think and write these few words on my keyboard. (By the way it's my 1st post)

Then there is Quran and its scientific miracles. To cite just one :

- Expansion of the universe : And We have built the heaven with might and We continue to expand it indeed. 51:48

You can do a search for the scientific miracles of the Quran, and while reading the verses (or the translated version) remember that it was revealed more than 1400 years ago to the Prophet Muhammed (PBUH) who was completely unlettered and ask yourself: How could he know that fact at that time?